Por que essa medida não está dando certo? Medida COUNTROWS do Power BI não retorna resultado
Medida do Power BI retorna "(Em branco)" ou "-" no cartão. Olá, galera! Sou iniciante nessa área e tenho enfrentado muitos problemas (ja já a calvice vem) faz uns 4 dias que estou tentando achar algum erro na minha medida que conta as linhas de uma coluna seguindo uma série de condições. Ao fazer a medida ela não retorna erro mas sim uma visualização em branco ou com um -. Já chequei os nomes das tabelas e colunas e estão certinhos, não sei o que pode ser. Explicando um pouco, tenho um formulário do forms e baixo as respostas para um excel importando no power bi e tratando os dados lá. A minha ideia era incluir algumas colunas da tabela de perguntas na tabela de respostas mas eu não consegui então acrescentei uma consulta a outra e chamei de Tabela Combinada, o que me trouxe dados nulos em muitas colunas. A media é está:
categoria001 = 
    IF(
        COUNTROWS(FILTER(Tabela_Combinada, Tabela_Combinada[Perguntas] = "Existe HISTÓRICO junto aos órgãos intervenientes de licenciamento ambiental ?" && Tabela_Combinada[Respostas]= "Sim")) > 0,
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                Tabela_Combinada,
                'Tabela_Combinada'[Perguntas]= "Existe HISTÓRICO junto aos órgãos intervenientes de licenciamento ambiental ?" && 
                'Tabela_Combinada'[Respostas] = "Sim "
            ),
            'Tabela_Combinada'[Peso]
        ),
        "-"
    )

Detalhe: a medida não funciona em nenhum gráfico

É o mesmo problema dessa que perguntou pouco antes? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/594998/medida-do-power-bi-retorna-em-branco-ou-no-cart%c3%a3o - para evitar duplicação de conteúdo bloqueei os comentários aqui, mas o espaço pode ser usado na postagem original. Edite aquela para que possa ser reavaliada.
